# In Selenium launching a browser in Incognito mode using CRTL + Shift + N is not working in Sauce Labs

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, saucelabs, incognito-mode

I have tests where I need to Login with roles in the application so I am using CRTL+Shift+N for incognito mode in local machine, but when coming to Saucelabs it is unable to open incognito mode.

what is the solution for tests to run in incognito mode while testing with multiple roles scenario?

Comment: `ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("--incognito");` use this

Comment: @Dev thanks for your answer but when we use options.addArguments("--incognito"); it will always launch browser in the incognito mode which is my not requirement. I need to open incognito mode in the middle of the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To launch chrome in incognito mode, you need to add argument `--incognito` as below:

**Chrome:**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
```

**Firefox:**

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addArguments("-private");
```

**Note:** To open the incognito mode in the middle of the scenario, create another chrome driver instance with the above arguments.